# Implementing common logic with scripting language for re-using on .NET, Silverlight, Android and iOS

Tags: android, .net, ios, silverlight

There's a pretty complicated client-server application. Server-side is .NET, and 3 clients are Silverlight + 2 native clients for Android and iOS. We're considering moving some of the server-side logic to clients. Implementing this logic "natively" requires big efforts and for sure will cause a lot of bugs, so we're thinking about implementing this shared logic using scripting and then just embedding script engines to the every client application.

Is there a scripting language that works the same way on platforms listed below?

- .NET
- Silverlight
- Android
- iOS

We're considering:

- *(I know it's not scripting)* **Mono/MonoTouch/MonoDroid**. Looks like there's pretty large memory usage overhead and since our client applications are pretty heavy, using Mono seems to be bad idea.
- **Lua**. Can easily be integrated with .NET, Android and iOS, but feels like there are no de-facto implementations for Silverlight.
- *(I know it's not scripting)* **C/C++**. Doesn't work with Silverlight.

---

1. What are the other options to consider?
2. If you had relevant experience what did you use?